# Why my while loop failed (python)?

Tags: python, while-loop, dynamic-programming

I'm a new learner of python programming. Recently I'm trying to write a "tool" program of "dynamic programming" algorithm. However, the last part of my programe -- a `while` loop, failed to loop. the code is like

```
import numpy as np

beta, rho, B, M = 0.5, 0.9, 10, 5
S = range(B + M + 1)  # State space = 0,...,B + M
Z = range(B + 1)      # Shock space = 0,...,B 

def U(c):      
    "Utility function."
    return c**beta

def phi(z):    
    "Probability mass function, uniform distribution."
    return 1.0 / len(Z) if 0 <= z <= B else 0

def Gamma(x):  
    "The correspondence of feasible actions."
    return range(min(x, M) + 1)

def T(v):      
    """An implementation of the Bellman operator.
    Parameters: v is a sequence representing a function on S.
    Returns: Tv, a list."""
    Tv = []        
    for x in S:
        # Compute the value of the objective function for each 
        # a in Gamma(x), and store the result in vals (n*m matrix)
        vals = []   
        for a in Gamma(x):
            y = U(x - a) + rho * sum(v[a + z]*phi(z) for z in Z)
            # the place v comes into play, v is array for each state
            vals.append(y)
        # Store the maximum reward for this x in the list Tv
        Tv.append(max(vals))
    return Tv 

# create initial value
def v_init():    
    v = []
    for i in S:
        val = []
        for j in Gamma(i):
            # deterministic 
            y = U(i-j)
            val.append(y)
        v.append(max(val))
    return v    

# Create an instance of value function          
v = v_init()

# parameters
max_iter = 10000
tol = 0.0001
num_iter = 0
diff = 1.0
N = len(S)

# value iteration
value = np.empty([max_iter,N])
while (diff>=tol and num_iter<max_iter ):
    v = T(v)
    value[num_iter] = v
    diff = np.abs(value[-1] - value[-2]).max()   
    num_iter = num_iter + 1
```

As you can see, the `while` loop at the bottom is used to iterate over "value function" and find the right answer. However, the while fails to loop, and just return `num_iter=1`. As for I know, the while loop "repeats a sequence of statements until some condition becomes false", clearly, this condition will not be satisfied until the diff converge to near 0
  The major part of code works just fine, as far as I use the following `for` loop

```
value = np.empty([num_iter,N])
for x in range(num_iter):
    v = T(v)
    value[x] = v
diff = np.abs(value[-1] - value[-2]).max()  
print(diff)
```

Comment: `value` is full of zeros, so  `diff` will be zero in the first loop. Now `diff >= tol` is `False` and the loop breaks.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You define `value` as `np.empty(...)`.  That means that it is composed completely of zeros.  The difference, therefore, between the last element and the second-to-last element will be zero. `0` is *not* `>= 0.0001`, so that expression will be `False`.  Therefore, your loop breaks.

Comment: Thanks, so what kinds of array I can choose if I need a place holder for `value`? Or what should I do to change the condition ?

Comment: If you want to get the same effect as the `for` loop that is mentioned in your question, use `while num_iter < max_iter:`.

Comment: However, I want to let the program decide how many iterations it needs. Imaging, I want to know the exact `num_iter` when `diff<tol`.

Comment: I don't know what the whole program is supposed to do, but how it is now, you are modifying `value[num_iter]` which at the beginning of the loop is `value[0]`, but you are checking the difference between `value[-1]` and `value[-2]`.  Those last two values are not changed until the end of the `while` loop; but they aren't changed at all, because the `while` loop doesn't get that far.  If you start `num_iter` at `len(value) - 1`, use `num_iter>0` instead of `num_iter<max_iter`, and say `num_iter = num_iter - 1` instead of `num_iter = num_iter + 1`; then it runs, but I don't know if it's right.

Comment: Thanks , your point out the curx, I change the `value[-1] - value[-2]` to `value[num_iter] - value[num_iter-1]` and it finally works